# When Plotted Numpy PolyFit Does Not Fit Curve to Points

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, optimization

I wrote the following python code for fitting a curve to the provided points. The curve does not appear to follow the provided points. What I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
# Install required dependencies 
!pip install scikit-optimize


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

x_values = np.array([0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3, 0.31, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55])

y_values = np.array([0.00103, 0.000953, 0.00081, 0.00073, 0.000692, 0.000659, 0.00066, 0.000671, 0.000693, 0.000688, 0.000812, 0.000928, 0.001075, 0.001228])

plt.plot(x_values, y_values, 'o')

plt.plot(np.polyval(poly, x_values), color="red", label='fit')


# Print polynomial coefficients

print(poly)

# This outputs: [ 0.00756766 -0.0041761   0.00125393]
```

Input points:

[image: input points]

Points with incorrectly fitted curve:
[image: points with incorrectly fitted curve]

I verified that the points are sorted in ascending order.

I tried rerunning the code. The output did not change.